# How do I delete local address book contacts?

Tags: thunderbird, contacts, address-book

How can I delete all my local address book contact from Ubuntu 12.10?

When I try to delete "personal address book" from thunder bird, I got this error

> Sorry - this version of EDS Contacts Integration does not support
>   deleting Evolution address books. Due to the way that Thunderbird
>   tries to delete address books, all of your EDS address books will
>   appear to be removed from the address book manager.  Simply restart
>   Thunderbird in order to have them return.

Also I do not find a way to delete local contacts using "gnome-contacts".

Extra information : All my contacts were imported from my mobile phone used "Sync" application

Comment: Why my question was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Evolution installed in gnome, you have actually two pieces of software: the Evolution client, and the Evolution Data Server (EDS which is package 'evolution-data-server-common' ). The latter allows the contacts to be shared between various other address books (like in Thunderbird and Gnome).

If you are not using evolution at all, you can uninstall it. EDS should be kept (it is not uninstalled in this process), so that other applications can also use it. You can also keep (or you can disable it if you want) the EDS contact integration add-on in TB. Since you are able to sync your mobile contacts with ubuntu, then you should notice under your TB address book a group 'contacts' which is updated automatically since you have EDS integration.

You can give more details in your question about the applications you have running regarding contacts.